# ClickOnce solution publishing old project

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application that I publish to a web location so users can download an install in their machines. Is not a web only application. You can download it and use it offline.

I just had a problem with Dropbox completely messing up my project folder, but since I keep zipped copies of my whole solution every time I publish, I just got rid of my messed up project and restored my latest zipped solution, which was version 2.3.2.0. Then I made a few changes, increased version to 2.3.2.6, and published. After installing, the version was still showing 2.3.2.0 in the about box (and I can tell it was the old version by not seeing the latest changes).

When I just run the project, the version is the right one (2.3.2.6), and if I publish to a local folder, still the version is the right one. Only when I publish via ftp to my online location, I get the older version every time I install the application. I tried publishing to a new folder (so no older versions should be there), and installing to my XP virtual machine, and keep getting the old version.

Also, if I download the `myApplication.exe.deploy` file from the server and look at the version with reflector, I see the right version. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332544/returning-clickonce-version-doesnt-work-when-launching-application-on-startup-f